# Netflix problem with Ubuntu

Tags: netflix-desktop

I'm very new to Ubuntu, and yesterday I wanted to watch top gear on netflix.
I was using Chromium snd I read that it doesn't support drm (I think it was called) and flash.

I tried the desktop version and installing it through terminal, and it doesn't work either.
Then, I installed Chrome, and it works.
Is there any way I can install desktop netflix?
And how do I remove everything?

Comment: So using Google chrome solves your problem, you want to install Netflix and then you want to remove "everything"? Please be clear.

Comment: Sorry, using netflix in Chrome is a little "lame", and I installed the desktop version in terminal and I want to remove it completley from the system, and reinstall.:)

Comment: What do you mean by lame, why do you want to reinstall?

Comment: I don't actually know, I just think it's lame... And I want to use the desktop version.

Comment: There is no stand-alone Netflix app. Chrome shows Netflix out of the box; Netflix can be also made to work on Firefox by installing a Wine-wrapper around Silverlight, called Pipelight, and fooling Netflix into believing that you are actually on a Windows PC. At least, that used to work around a year ago. See e.g. [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/01/how-to-watch-lovefilm-redbox-instant-or-netflix-on-ubuntu).